# Weblogic ResourceLimitException with JNDI data-source

Tags: oracle, weblogic

I have deployed a third party web-application onto my Weblogic server and this application connects to Oracle Database using JNDI data-source that I have defined in my weblogic server. Now while I use the web-application, I don't see any issues, and after accessing the application for a while it throws an exception as below-

```
weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceLimitException: No resources currently available in pool test_db to allocate to applications, please increase the size of the pool and retry.. caused by: weblogic.jdbc.extensions.PoolLimitSQLException:
```

How can I debug this issue using my weblogic server? Is there any log file that contains details on why all the connections are still used?

Comment: Here's a detailed explanation on what to do -http://www.albinsblog.com/2012/10/resourcelimitexception-no-resources.html#.UvV2U_ldUXU

Answer (score 2):

Steps:

1. Go to WLS Console
2. Select Services -> Datasources -> select the datasource you want to change the pool size
3. Go to Configuration -> connection pool
4. Change the Maximum Capacity to the count which is required for your application.

Comment: I have already done that earlier, my issue is if my web-application application is not in use for few hours and if I try to start using it then I am facing this issue. So I want to know how/why the connections are still being used.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
You can see this : http://www.albinsblog.com/2012/10/resourcelimitexception-no-resources.html#.VqX7-U_YRnm

The problem is there was too much waiting for connection to JDBC Datasource. For this, I increased the number of connections in the connection pool, like the recommandations in the link.